Why does the Jacobian matrix arrange derivatives differently compared to the Gradient Vector?
gradient vector
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} \\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}
\end{bmatrix}
jacobian
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n} \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n}
\end{bmatrix}
Question:
Why is there a discrepancy in the arrangement of derivatives between the Gradient Vector and the Jacobian Matrix? Specifically:

When differentiating a scalar function, the gradient vector associates each component of ( x ) with a row in the gradient (resulting in a column vector).

When differentiating a vector or matrix function, the Jacobian matrix associates each component of ( x ) with a column in the Jacobian.


This seems contradictory in terms of the orientation of derivatives (rows vs. columns). Can someone explain the reasoning behind these conventions and why they differ between scalar and vector/matrix functions?

Who said that the gradient has to be a column vector?

You have indeed identified an inconsistency in these particular choices. The standard thing is for columns to correspond to inputs and rows to correspond to outputs, as in your Jacobian matrix. So the gradient of a function $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ ought to be $1 \times n$ (row), and dually the tangent of a parametrization function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^m$ ought to be a $m \times 1$ (column).
